# Remove HTML tags from a text field in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that contains a text field, and I want to remove some of the existing HTML tags in the text field. Can anyone help me find a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the text field, set property **Markup** to **HTML**. This should solve.

Comment: This does not work, as the text field only supports a very limted set of HTML tags. When unsupported tags are detected, the result is a blank field. (As of Jaspersoft Studio 6.18.1)

Comment: @Cris70 It depends on the use case. It's true that this is not working well for styling as the support of HTML tags is far too limited. However if the goal is just to remove HTML tags to display the content, this approach is simple and clean.

Comment: @Mariposa I do not have an installation of Jaspersoft Studio anymore unfortunately, so I cannot test recent releases. However, with version 6.18.1 this solution was not working, as even one unsupported tag in the text would result in a completely empty field on exit.
So no, even if it is just to remove HTML (which was my original intent) this is NOT the solution.

Answer (score 1):

My (not perfect unfortunately) workaround:

```
$F{address}.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IReport for designing you report go to your text field properties (placed in the right of the main editor) and go to "Text properties" and choose html for markup

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
cleanText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

Comment: how to combine expression text field (address) with iReport designer? -->  $F{address}